# Mounting NFSv4 share from Debian Linux 6 to Freebsd 9-RC3 "server requires stronger authentication"

Tags: linux, solaris, freebsd, nfs, nfs4

I've run into a strange problem while trying to mount from FreeBSD 9.0-RC3 to a Debian Linux box.

The command I'm using is:

sudo mount -v gorkon:/dustbin /tmp/test

This returns the following immediate information:

mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jan  5 17:37:40 2012
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=[serverip],clientaddr=[cllientaddr]'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting gorkon:/dustbin

There's no log entry that I can find on the server (gorkon), and the following log entry is in my syslog for the debian box:

[30082.224612] RPC: server gorkon requires stronger authentication.

The NFS server has nfsuserd running, rpcbind running. I've tried to set the share in /etc/exports to use sec=sys (and connect the same way). I don't have Kerberos set up on this network, and I'm not about to start. The Debian NFSv4 servers do connect to a Solaris 10 NFSv4 server, and the FreeBSD box can't mount its own shares over NFS if I force use of nfsv4 (error is mount_nfs: /tmp/test, : Permission denied). A FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE box won't mount either, same error.

The Solaris 10 box also cannot mount the FreeBSD box's mount. The error for this machine is :

genunix: [ID 664466 kern.notice]  NFS compound failed for server gorkon: error 7
genunix: [ID 532867 kern.warning] WARNING: NFS server initial call to gorkon failed: permission denied.

NFSv3 mounts work fine.

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, make sure you have a "V4:" root line in /etc/exports, like so:

```
V4: / -sec=sys
/tank/dedup host1 host2 host3
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified an authentification type on the FreeBSD Server and on your cmd to mount from it? FreeBSD afaik requires that for NFSv4.

> sec=⟨flavor⟩
>                        This option specifies what security flavor should be used
>                        for the mount.  Currently, they are:

```
                 krb5 ‐  Use KerberosV authentication
                 krb5i ‐ Use KerberosV authentication and
                         apply integrity checksums to RPCs
                 krb5p ‐ Use KerberosV authentication and
                         encrypt the RPC data
                 sys ‐   The default AUTH_SYS, which uses a
                         uid + gid list authenticator
```

See mount_nfs(8)

Comment: I've set sec=sys in both exports (tried ZFS attribute and /etc/exports separately) and mounting with -o sec=sys on the client boxes and the server itself.
The server just replies with "Permission Denied" from mount_nfs (no entries in dmesg), and the linux client boxes state "access denied by server" and leave a message in the /var/log/messages from RPC regarding the server wanting stronger authentication. NFSv3 seems to work.

Comment: I've posted a bug report with FreeBSD for now.

Comment: Yeah, that may actually be a good guess. I've messed with NFSv4 on FreeBSD when it first came out and had some trouble with this, too. Ultimately I gave up, because there still were some known issues with sec_sys back then. Sadly NFSv4 also is poorly documented imo, so its hard to see if this still is one of those old bugs or ones own fault.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side in FreeBSD you need the following lines in /etc/rc.conf

```
nfs_server_enable="YES"
nfsv4_server_enable="YES"
nfsuserd_enable="YES"
```

and this would be the simplest possible /etc/exports

```
V4: /
/
```

On the Debian client end, you want to mount it using NFSv4 like so:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs4 test.home:/ /mnt
```

You want to replace test.home with the IP or hostname of your NFS server, and you can replace /mnt with whatever mount point you want to use.

You can check the protocol used by looking at the output of this command:

```
$ mount
test.home:/ on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,addr=192.168.1.5,clientaddr=192.168.1.3)
```